# Input type file top of the page

Tags: css

How to put input type file at the center of the page. Which is currently displays from top of the margin

```
<style>
input[type="file"]
{
display: none;
}
label{
background-color: red;
padding: 25px 4px;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
border:2px solid transparent;
}
label::selection{
background-color: yellow;
}
label:hover{
border-style: solid;
border-top-color: #92a8d1;
border-right-color: navy;
border-bottom-color: teal;
border-left-color: #1abc9c;
transition: all 2s linear;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can u be more specific what do u mean by center of the page? horizontally or vertically or both?

Comment: Both please. But i would like to be at the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#input_file {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 400px;
}
input[type="file"]
{
  display: none;
}
label{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 25px 4px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
label::selection{
  background-color: yellow;
}
label:hover{
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #92a8d1;
  border-right-color: navy;
  border-bottom-color: teal;
  border-left-color: #1abc9c;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="input_file">
      <label for="file">Input file</label>
      <input type="file" id="file"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can add parent div with `display: flex;` and use flex properties like `justify-content: center;` for vertically center and `align-items: center;` for horizontally center.

Also in order to make `justify-content` works, you need to define the height of the parent.